# Preferences NVS can not save array over 11 bytes

Tags: arduino-ide, c++, esp32

Why can't I store arrays with size over 11 bytes inside Preferences using  putBytes.

> this code is not telling whole story
> here is complete code to show the problem. I put the console output down...

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Preferences.h>

struct Config_wifi_t{
  String WIFI_SSID;
  String WIFI_PASSWORD;
};

bool save_config(Config_wifi_t config_wifi){
    log_d("save_config Start");

    Preferences prefs;
    prefs.begin("c_wifi"); // Name space m_config
   
    prefs.putBytes("c_wifi", &config_wifi, sizeof(config_wifi));
    prefs.end();
  return true;
}

Config_wifi_t get_config(){
    Preferences prefs;
    Config_wifi_t config_wifi;
    prefs.begin("c_wifi"); 
    size_t schLen = prefs.getBytesLength("c_wifi");  
    
    char buffer[schLen]; 

    if(schLen==0){ 
        log_d("EMPTY MEMORY");
        return config_wifi;
    }
    
    prefs.getBytes("c_wifi", buffer, schLen); 

    Config_wifi_t *c_wifi = (Config_wifi_t *) buffer; 
    config_wifi = *c_wifi;
    prefs.end();  
    return config_wifi;
}

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("Starting");
  Config_wifi_t config_wifi;
  config_wifi.WIFI_SSID="network";
  config_wifi.WIFI_PASSWORD="LongStringForTest";

  Serial.println("Saving...");
  save_config(config_wifi);
  Serial.println("Saved");

  Serial.println("Read");
  Config_wifi_t config_wifi2;
  config_wifi2 = get_config();
  Serial.println("Read");
  Serial.print("WIFI_SSID=");
  Serial.println(config_wifi2.WIFI_SSID);
  Serial.print("WIFI_PASSWORD=");
  Serial.println(config_wifi2.WIFI_PASSWORD);
}

void loop() {
}
```

*This are the output with: config_wifi.WIFI_PASSWORD="LongStringForTest";*

```
Starting
Saving...
[D][main.cpp:10] save_config(): save_config Start
Saved
Read
Read
WIFI_SSID=network
WIFI_PASSWORD=es
```

*This are the output with: config_wifi.WIFI_PASSWORD="Short";*

```
Starting
Saving...
[D][main.cpp:10] save_config(): save_config Start
Saved
Read
Read
WIFI_SSID=network
WIFI_PASSWORD=Short
```

Comment: I guess `putBytes` will not 'follow' the pointer. `sizeof(configuration_i)` is `sizeof(bool) + sizeof(int*) + sizeof(config_general_t)`

Comment: I try with prefs.putBytes("m_config", configuration_i, sizeof(bool) + sizeof(int*) + sizeof(config_general_t));

Not work

Comment: why would you do that?

Comment: I don't think I understood your comment then.

Comment: if size of array is 10 bytes work without problems but is bigger than 10 not work

Comment: `sizeof(configuration_i)` is the size of **that specific data structure**. It is an array of one (1) struct `configuration_t`. The size of that struct is the size of its data members: as @Juraj said, that's the size of one bool, one struct `config_wifi_t`, and one other struct. You may be confused by the size of the pointer (which is often 8 bytes) versus the size of the thing the pointer points to -- which could be anything, really, and `sizeof()` can not know about it.

Comment: I understand what you're saying.
Do you have any idea how to solve the problem?

Comment: I update the question with new code and example.

Comment: String manages a pointer to a char array. you now store the 'manager' but not the data

Comment: why the behavior changes when the length of the string is less than 11 characters?.  notice that when config_wifi.WIFI_PASSWORD = "Short" it works fine

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a ptr and life cycle problem.

This are working code.

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Preferences.h>

struct Config_wifi_t{
  bool result;
  char WIFI_SSID[50];
  char WIFI_PASSWORD[50];
};

bool save_config(Config_wifi_t *config_wifi){
    log_d("save_config Start");

    Preferences prefs;
    prefs.begin("c_wifi");
   
    prefs.putBytes("c_wifi", config_wifi, sizeof(Config_wifi_t));
    prefs.end();
  return true;
}

Config_wifi_t get_config(){
    Preferences prefs;
    prefs.begin("c_wifi"); 
    size_t schLen = prefs.getBytesLength("c_wifi");  
    
    char buffer[schLen]; 

    Config_wifi_t *_config_wifi = (Config_wifi_t *) buffer;

    if(schLen==0){ 
        log_d("EMPTY MEMORY");        
        _config_wifi->result=false;
        return *_config_wifi;
    }
    
    prefs.getBytes("c_wifi", buffer, schLen); 

  if (schLen % sizeof(Config_wifi_t)) { // simple check that data fits
    log_e("Data is not correct size!");
      _config_wifi->result=false;
      return *_config_wifi;
  }    
    _config_wifi = (Config_wifi_t *) buffer; 
    return _config_wifi[0];
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("Starting");
  struct Config_wifi_t config_wifi;
  
  strcpy(config_wifi.WIFI_SSID,"network");
  strcpy(config_wifi.WIFI_PASSWORD,"LongStringForTest");

  Serial.println("Saving...");
  save_config(&config_wifi);
  Serial.println("Saved");

  Serial.println("Read");
  
  Config_wifi_t confFromNvs;
  confFromNvs = get_config();
  Serial.println("Readed");
  log_e("WIFI_SSID %s",confFromNvs.WIFI_SSID);
  log_e("WIFI_SSID %s",confFromNvs.WIFI_PASSWORD);
}

void loop() {
}
```

console output:

```
[E][main.cpp:66] setup(): WIFI_SSID network
[E][main.cpp:67] setup(): WIFI_SSID LongStringForTest
```

thanks to the people that help.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).